# Better way to write a script for better error detection, time and resource efficiency?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting

I need suggestions on how to improve the below script for better efficiency ( both time and resource, and for better error detection). Here is a simple description on what the script does:

Functionality: The script runs in crontab for "ins" user very minute, searches for a .DAT file in "input path". If it finds the .dat file, moves it to "working directory", executes it as a batch, and after completion of the execution of .dat file moves it to "output folder". The .dat file contains a series a similar commands to insert numbers into database.

```
    #!/usr/bin/ksh

    def_path="/apps/ins/"
    env_path="/apps/ins/eir/bin"
    input_path="/apps/ins/eir/batch/input/"
    work_path="/apps/ins/eir/batch/working/"
    output_path="/apps/ins/eir/batch/output/"
    moved_path="/apps/ins/eir/batch/processed/"
    log="/apps/ins/BLA/log/"
    date=`date '+%d%b%y'`

    cd $input_path
    listcount=`ls -rt *.dat |wc -l`
    list=`ls -rt *.dat`
    echo "`date +%H:%M:%S`| Total No of DAT files available are # $listcount #\nName of the files are...\n         $list "  >> $log/$date.log  2>&1

    if [[ -e $def_path/.bla_processing ]];
    then
       echo "`date +%H:%M:%S`| Script is already running" >> $log/$date.log  2>&1
       exit
    fi

    for fname in `ls *.dat | awk -F. '{print $1}'`
    do

    touch $def_path/.bla_processing
    mv $input_path/$fname.dat $work_path/$fname.dat

    echo "##################################################"  >> $log/$date.log  2>&1
    echo "## Filename = $fname.dat ## Time = `date +%H:%M:%S` ##"  >> $log/$date.log  2>&1 
    echo "##################################################"  >> $log/$date.log  2>&1 
    cd $env_path
    . /apps/ins/.profile   >> $log/$date.log  2>&1
    echo "Username is `whoami`" >> $log/$date.log  2>&1

    $env_path/mip_cmd EXECUTE:$work_path/$fname.dat,$output_path/$fname.out,100; >> $log/$date.log  2>&1
    sleep 2
    echo "`date +%H:%M:%S`| Moving the file *** $fname.dat *** to path |$moved_path|"  >> $log/$date.log  2>&1 
    mv $work_path/$fname.dat $moved_path/$fname.dat.moved
    cmd_exec=`cat $output_path/$fname.out |grep ":" |wc -l`
    echo "`date +%H:%M:%S`| Total commands executed are `expr $cmd_exec / 2`"  >> $log/$date.log  2>&1 
    echo "`date +%H:%M:%S`| Total Sucessfully executed commands are `cat $output_path/$fname.out |grep         "C1:00000;" |wc -l`"  >> $log/$date.log  2>&1 
    echo "--------------------------------------------------"  >> $log/$date.log  2>&1
    echo "#### SCRIPT WILL PROCESS THE NEXT FILE ###########"  >> $log/$date.log  2>&1
    echo "--------------------------------------------------"  >> $log/$date.log  2>&1
    echo ""  >> $log/$date.log  2>&1
    rm $def_path/.bla_processing
    exit
    done
```

Comment: Shell scripts create processes like crazy. Are you sure a shell script is the best option here if you're worried about resource use?

Comment: @tjameson Are you suggesting to write it in perl, basically the end user is not comfortable in perl, so i don't see much option, other than  shell script

Comment: You didn't mention anything about the end user, but generally when a script gets long enough, I rewrite it in something faster, like Python. If you need efficiency, then you'll get more mileage out of a full programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using "$def_path/.bla_processing" as a form of lock, you should probably check its existense first thing before you proceed with the rest of the script.

Also, "touch $def_path/.bla_processing" and "rm $def_path/.bla_processing" could be moved out of the for loop.

What your code is doing now is, only the first file is processed, and the script will exit. So the call to "exit" in the end of the for loop is not necessary.

As an example (after applying the above suggestions):

```
touch $def_path/.bla_processing
for fname in `ls *.dat | awk -F. '{print $1}'`
    ....
    # remove the call to exit
done
rm $def_path/.bla_processing
```